# How to add CuePoint to a rtmp stream with ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, rtmp

I am trying to build a teaching application using flash player. My idea is that when the teacher does something, such as changing the slides, the javascript calls the SWF interface which adds CuePoints to the rtmp stream, while the students listening on the CuePoint event, they are able to synchronize what the teacher is doing.

So I did my research and found out that I had to write some server-side script/module to support this. I tried Wowza Server and wrote a Java Module which defined a handler function so the AS was able to call

```
netconnection.call("handler_function", null, "myStream", arg1, arg2);
```

But sadly, I am using a third-party streaming cloud so I can't write server-side code. Is there any way to add the CuePoint only on the client side with ActionScript?

Answer (score 0):

Dont have enough to mark a comment so posting it here. I did not use FMS/wowza recently, but using FMS I used to do this like the example at https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1152718?tstart=0

hope this will work same on wowza too. Thanks